# How to update column in database in blade.php file Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hello I have row in a database table have an id and name and etc.. and active = 1
I want in blade.php file when someone click a button it change into 0 in 1 click

What I tried is `{{$referral_detail->update('active', 1)}}`

And

```
{{$referral_detail->IDT->where('active', 0)->update('active', 1)}}
```

Function in Controller is

```
public function DriverReferAll()
{
    $query = DriverReferralDiscount::where([['referral_driver_id', '!=', 0],
        ['referral_sender_id', '!=', 0], ['active', '<>', 1]
    ]);


    $referral_details = $query->paginate(25);


    return view('merchant.driver.driver_referall', compact('referral_details', 'query'));
}
```

I got it `thedit('{{$referral_detail->IDT->update(['active' => 1])}}')`

and function

```
function thedit(a) {

    $("input:submit").val(a);
}
```

But when I do it , it change the first 2 column not only 1 tho I put the specific id any idea?

its in onClick""

```
<span onClick=" thedit('{{$referral_detail->IDT->update(['active' => 1])}}')
                                        " data-target="#addMoneyModel"
                                              data-toggle="modal" id="{{ $referral_detail->GetterDriver->id }}"><a
                                                    data-original-title="Add Money"
                                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                    id="{{ $referral_detail->GetterDriver->id }}" data-placement="top"
                                                    class="btn text-white btn-sm btn-success menu-icon btn_detail action_btn"> <i
                                                        class="fa fa-money-bill"></i> </a></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you must create a link in your blade template when that link is clicked It must have an href which point to the laravel route which will perform the update of your active state.

```
<a href="{{ route('your_route_name', ['id' => $referral_detail->id]) }}>Change</a>
```

the route can be define like this

```
Route::get('/route_path/{id}', 'ControllerName@action_name')->name('route_name');
```

Or If you want the browser to not refresh you can perform and **Ajax**

Comment: Oh thanks! but what should i put in the function? is there a function or just that?

Comment: Like I said you must create a controller which will receive the ID of the item you want to update and in that controller you retrieve that Item from the database  and perform the update

Comment: I did this its missed up ?

public function editUpdate($id)
    {
        DriverReferralDiscount::where([['id', $id]])->update(['active' => 1]);


        return redirect()->back()->with('History', 'Done');
    }

Comment: Thank you Worked!! can i put 2 actions for 1 button? like 2 routs? to do 2 things?